# Database model correction mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a database of 3 tables: "products", "brands" and "categories".

products table has `product_id`, `brand_id`, `category_id`, etc. So by using `category_id` and `brand_id` from other tables, I can pick up and show the different data from product table.

However, I want a solution like, for example, what if a product lies in two or more categories? What should be the database model and what table changes should I need to do more in my database?

My table structures are listed below:

- Database:

  [image: database]
- Brand table:

  [image: brand table]
- Category table:

  [image: category table]
- Product table:

  [image: product table]

Comment: You'd need an intermediate table that holds relations from `product` to `category`. This table would have `product_id` and `category_id` as fields (key), so a product can have many categories.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping cardinalities between product and category table are many to many. So you have to create a new table to keep records product and category relationship according to database normalization. SO remove category_id from the product table and create a table like as the below. For example

```
create table productCategory(
product_id integer references product_table(product_id),
category_id interger references category_table(category_id),
primary key (product_id,category_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is two solution from my logic:

1. Change type of cat_id column in product table, using VARCHAR or TEXT, so each product have cat_id with separated by comma or colon, example value: **1,4,5**
2. Remove column cat_id from product table, Add another table for mapping product into cat_id, example scheme:

   CREATE TABLE `product_mapping` (
       `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `product_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
       `cat_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   )

So.. you can query by joining 3 table for product information, with example query as below:

```
SELECT pm.cat_id AS m_cat_id, pm.product_id AS m_product_id, p.*, c.*
FROM product_mapping AS pm
INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.id = pm.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.cat_id = pm.cat_id
WHERE pm.product_id = :produc_id
```